# I want to be able to group same file sequence from a list python

Tags: python, list, path, sequence

Working on a python function which parses a file containing a list of strings.
Basically a walked folder structure parsed to a txt file so I don't have to work on real raid while in prod. That is also a requirement. To work from a txt file containing list of paths.

```
lpaths  =[
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot012/render/SC11_1_Shot012.v01_1025.exr',
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot012/render/SC11_1_Shot012.v01_1042.exr',
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot012/render/SC11_1_Shot012.v01_1016.exr',
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot012/2d/app/Shot012_v1.exr',
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot012/2d/app/Shot012_v02.exr',
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot004/3d/app2/workspace.cfg',
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot004/3d/app2/scenes/SC11_1_Shot004_v01.exr',
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot004/3d/app2/scenes/Shot004_camera_v01.exr',
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot004/render/SC11_1_Shot004.v01_1112.exr',
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot004/render/SC11_1_Shot004.v01_1034.exr',
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot004/render/SC11_1_Shot004.v02_1116.exr',
    '/projects/0100/dbu/shots/11_1/SC11_1_Shot004/render/SC11_1_Shot004.v02_1126.exr'
    ]
```

This is partial list of the cleaned list version ive already worked out and works fine.

The real problem, need to parse all frames from a folder to into a list so it can hold a proper listed sequence.
There could be 1 frame or 1000, also there are multiple sequences in same folder as seen in the list.

My goal is to have a list for each sequence in a folder, so I can push them ahead to do more work down the road.

Code:

```
groups = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(lpaths), len)]

pp.pprint(groups)
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: "Basically a walked folder structure parsed to a txt file" ... "The real problem, need to parse all frames from a folder to into a list so it can hold a proper listed sequence." ... "My goal is to have a list for each sequence in a folder" ...what's a frame? What's a sequence? When you say "in a folder", why didn't you *serialize* (not "parse") in some using something like JSON, which would have maintained at least the folder structure...?

Comment: the json question i dont have answer for.

Comment: The last folder contains files and the folder structure is maped to tasks and workload. this is what ivegot, and have to work with. My effort is to consolidate RAIDs content to conform to new media managment system. Frame in this context is an EXR graphic file, sequence is a list of frames im trying to get. Unique based on the name and version.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have differing naming conventions you need to write a function that takes a single string and, *possibly using regular expressions*, returns an unambiguous key for you to sort on, lets say that you names are critically identified by the shot number which can be identified by `r".*[Ss]hot_?(\d+).*\.ext"` you could return an integer for the match base 10 so discarding any leading 0s.

Since you also may have a version number you could do a similar operation to get an unambiguous version number, (and possibly only process the latest version of a given shot).